# replace <img> tag's src attribute from file content in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xhtml, nokogiri

Want to replace  tag's src attribute value in xhtml file content.

```
section_content = section.export_xhtml_content file_path
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(section_content)
unless doc.css('div.image_content').blank?
  doc.css('div.image_content img').each do |img|
    newsrc = File.basename img[:src]
    img.set_attribute('src', newsrc)
  end
end
```

Here src attribute get replaced. But getting XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity error. After replacing src attribute, resultant content should be in xhtml. Kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: give error stacktrace

Comment: Look [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/xml-parsing-error-xml-or-text-declaration-not-at-start-of-entity-1) and [here](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/WPBlankLine.html)

Comment: Error trace:XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity Location: file:////home/username/.mozilla/firefox/3ya1i37u.default/epub/194/section220140325-25214-1ncpacq9c7dc84687778b5f49088cd0e65c6e0bc062a4dd.xhtml Line Number 2, Column 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> ^