# replace img src attribute value in string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xhtml

I retrieving content from xhtml file. Content contains img tag with `src="/tmp/folder_name/file_name"`. I want to replace the src value from **"/tmp/folder_name/file_name"** to **"file_name"**. Below code is the way of getting content from xhtml. I tried with `Nokogiri::HTML(section_content)`. But the resultant content is not in xhtml. How to convert it back to xhtml or how to replace the src value from the content without `Nokogiri::HTML`

```
  section_content = section.export_xhtml_content file_path
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(section_content)
    unless doc.css('div.image_content').blank?
      doc.css('div.image_content img').each do |img|
        newsrc = File.basename img[:src]
        img.set_attribute('src', newsrc)
      end
    end
    section_content = doc.to_s
```

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>File 1: Chapter1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="page_styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body class="publitory">
    <h1 id="File_1_1">Chapter1</h1>
    <h2 id="File_1_2">Content1</h2>
    <h3 id="File_1_3">Content1.1</h3>
    <p/>
    <div style="width:25%; margin: 0 auto;" data-align="Middle" class="image_content">
       <img width="100%" src="/tmp/fog/development_publitory_bucket/uploads/user/b57030de-89ac-11e3-9cf2-bdfa8a998e1e/book/053bab68-b4b2-11e3-8ed6-996ec04a57ef/oeb_image/angel7eef59eb838ac763a43b936763dd184ec3324318.jpeg"/> 
       <div class="caption" style="clear:both;">Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content<br/></div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <p/>
   <h3 id="File_1_4">Content1.2</h3>
   <h2 id="File_1_5">Content2</h2>
   <h2 id="File_1_6">Content3</h2>
   <h2 id="File_1_7">Content4</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

After replacing src value by using Nokogiri, the resultant content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>File 1: Chapter1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="page_styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="publitory">
    <h1 id="File_1_1">Chapter1</h1>
    <h2 id="File_1_2">Content1</h2>
    <h3 id="File_1_3">Content1.1</h3>
    <p></p>
    <div style="width:25%; margin: 0 auto;" data-align="Middle" class="image_content">
      <img width="100%" src="angel7eef59eb838ac763a43b936763dd184ec3324318.jpeg">
      <div class="caption" style="clear:both;">Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content Content1.1 content<br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p></p>
    <h3 id="File_1_4">Content1.2</h3>
    <h2 id="File_1_5">Content2</h2>
    <h2 id="File_1_6">Content3</h2>
    <h2 id="File_1_7">Content4</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Resultant content should be perfect xhtml. Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, the proper way to improve on questions it to edit them, not post a new question that expands on [the earlier one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22637833/1016716).

Answer (score 1):

The basics steps you need to do:

1. Construct the document, for example with `Nokogiri::XML`
2. Find the target node with `.xpath` or `.css` query
3. Do any manipulations on the node with the interface provided by [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html)

Comment: yes I did like this:
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(section_content)
 unless doc.css('div.image_content').blank?
   doc.css('div.image_content img').each do |img|
     newsrc = File.basename img[:src]
     img.set_attribute('src', newsrc)
   end
 end
 section_content = doc.to_s

Comment: And so, what's the issue?

Comment: Edited question. Kindly check it. The resultant content should be in xhtml.

Comment: I tried regex section_content[/img.*?src="(.*?)"/i,1]. But it giving only first img tag. I want all img tags from the content. If this one works, my issue will be solved.

Comment: Add `g` option, i.e. `/img.*?src="(.*?)"/ig`.

Comment: Also I updated the answer, have you tried constructing with the `XML` instead? As parsing documents with XML in a more preferred way than using regexes.

Comment: Thank you so much ilyai. Nokogiri::XML is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.